# Yacc parser not detecting my language well

Tags: yacc, lex

I am new to yacc and I am trying to define some rules for my language.
I have written a grammar "well" and it runs and executes without an error but for some reason, it doesn't do  what it is supposed to do.

mylex.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myyacc.tab.h"
extern int yyval;
%}

/* KEEP TRACK OF LINE NUMBER*/
%option yylineno 

uppercase [A-Z]
lowercase [a-z]
alpha [{uppercase}{lowercase}]
digit [0-9]
alphanum [{alpha}{digit}]
id uppercase({alphanum}|_)*
int_literal [0-9]+
float_literal [0-9]+\.[0-9]+
string_literal \"[^\"]*\"
comment (##)(.)*(##)



%%


"int" {return INT;}
"float" {return FLOAT;}
"boolean" {return BOOLEAN;}
"if" {return IF;}
"else" {return ELSE;}
"end" {return END;}
"true" {return TRUE;}
"false" {return FALSE;}
"read" {return READ;}
"print" {return PRINT;}
"while" {return WHILE;}
"START" {return START;}
"END" {return END;}

"+" {return ADD;}
"-" {return SUB;}
"*" {return MUL;}
"/" {return DIV;}

"&&" {return LOG_AND;}
"||" {return LOG_OR;}
"!" {return LOG_NOT;}

"==" {return EQ;}
"<>" {return NEQ;}
"<" {return LT;}
"<=" {return LEQ;}
">" {return GT;}
">=" {return GEQ;}

"=" {return ASSIGN;}

"(" {return LPAREN;}
")" {return RPAREN;}
"{" {return LBRACE;}
"}" {return RBRACE;}

{int_literal} {return INT_LITERAL;}
{float_literal} {return FLOAT_LITERAL;}
{string_literal} {return STRING_LITERAL;}
{id} {return ID;}
{comment} { ; }

%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

myyacc.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int yylineno;
extern FILE* yyin;
extern int yyerror (char* msg);
extern char * yytext;
%}

/* definitions section start */

%token INT FLOAT BOOLEAN IF ELSE END TRUE FALSE READ PRINT WHILE START 
%token INT_LITERAL FLOAT_LITERAL STRING_LITERAL ID ERROR

%right ASSIGN
%right LOG_NOT

%left MUL DIV
%left ADD SUB
%left LPAREN RPAREN
%left LBRACE RBRACE
%left LT LEQ GT GEQ
%left EQ NEQ
%left LOG_AND
%left LOG_OR

%start program

/* definitions section end */

%%

/* rules section start */

program         : START statements END {printf("No syntax errors detected")};

statements      : statements statement
                | statement
                ;

statement       : dec_stmt
                | assignment_stmt
                | print_stmt
                | read_stmt
                | condition_stmt
                | while_stmt
                ;

dec_stmt        : type ID
                ;

type            : INT
                | FLOAT
                | BOOLEAN
                ;

assignment_stmt : ID ASSIGN expression
                ;

expression      : exp EQ exp
                | exp NEQ exp
                | exp LT exp
                | exp LEQ exp
                | exp GT exp
                | exp GEQ exp
                | exp
                ;

exp             : exp MUL exp
                | exp DIV exp
                | exp ADD exp
                | exp SUB exp
                | exp LOG_AND exp
                | exp LOG_OR exp
                | LOG_NOT exp
                | LPAREN exp RPAREN
                | INT_LITERAL
                | FLOAT_LITERAL
                | ID
                | TRUE
                | FALSE
                ;

print_stmt      : PRINT LPAREN ID RPAREN
                | PRINT LPAREN STRING_LITERAL RPAREN
                ;

read_stmt       : ID ASSIGN READ LPAREN RPAREN
                ;

condition_stmt  : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE statement RBRACE END
                | IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE statement RBRACE ELSE LBRACE statement RBRACE END
                ;

while_stmt      : WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE statement RBRACE
                ;

/* rules section end */

%%

/* auxiliary routines start */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // don't change this part
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r" );
    if(!yyparse())
            printf("\nParsing complete\n");
        else
            printf("\nParsing failed\n");
        
        fclose(yyin);

    return 0;
}

int yyerror (char* msg)
{
    printf("Line %d: %s near %s\n", yylineno, msg, yytext);
    exit(1);
}

/* auxiliary routines end */
```

Test case

```
START
int X12
float ABC1
DDe = 7
while(QNn >0) ## this a Comment ##
{ RLk9999 = ACc - 2
    CCC = true
}
if ( ACc ==5){ print ( " Inside IF inside Loop " ) } end }
print ( " Hello .. " )
END
```

Output

```
Line 3: syntax error near 12
```

It also gets the line number wrong.

I've been trying to see what I'm doing wrong for some time now and I'd really appreciate a second set of eyes.

Comment: Because of parser lookahead, bison/yacc parsers often read the first token of the following line before an error is noticed. That's why the error message says it is on line 3.

Comment: If you intend to ask for help again in the future, you might want to reconsider defacing your question. Orphaning answers like that is a good way to alienate potential responders.

Comment: Why is the code removed form the question?

Comment: Sorry for that. It was an assignment and my lecturer thought it was plagiarism

Comment: But this is not allowed since it 1) defaces the question and 2) by posting the question you grant the site the right to distribute the information posted. If you aren't allowed to post this code, then you shouldn't have posted it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use macros inside character classes. Inside a character class, pattern operators lose their special meaning, so when you write

```
alphanum [{alpha}{digit}]
```

you are defining a character class containing `{`, `}`, and the letters `adghilpt`. That doesn't match the `12` in `X12`.

Anyway, flex already has predefined sets of characters which you can include in your character classes:

```
* [:lower:]    a-z
* [:upper:]    A-Z
* [:alpha:]    [:lower:][:upper:]
* [:digit:]    0-9
* [:alnum:]    [:alpha:][:digit:]
```

Note that these can only be used inside a character class. So you could write your `id` pattern as

```
id [[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]*
```

without the need for any other macros.

Please see the [flex pattern documentation](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75196087/12131849), I've also noticed that my while_statement in the yacc file has only been set to accept only one statement in it's body